# Client permissions on serverless Azure Web PubSub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-pubsub

I've successfully followed the [Tutorial - Create a serverless chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/quickstart-serverless?tabs=javascript) using the Azure Web PubSub service.

Now I require giving the clients different permissions based on their ID. Also, add them to different groups.

[The documentation on this matter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/tutorial-permission) is using a NodeJs server, but it says nothing about how to accomplish this using serverless Functions.

Is there a piece of documentation I am missing? Do you have any lead or example to share on how to manipulate permission on the negotiate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging around, I finally found this repository with examples on what I wanted to accomplish:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webpubsub/blob/main/samples/functions/js/simplechat-wpscontext/connected/index.js